# How can I create a .desktop file that opens a directory in Nemo?

Tags: .desktop, nemo

How can I create a .desktop file that opens a directory in Nemo browser?

Comment: you could also set and use a bookmark in nemo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create .desktop launcher [as described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) and in `Exec` use the command `nemo` with your directory path. It may look like this:

```
Exec=nemo /home
```

Comment: If you don't want Nemo to manage the desktop, e. g. if you don't want to show the content of `~/Desktop` on the desktop or if you already have a different desktop file manage, you should add the `--no-desktop` flag. This won't change anything if Nemo is already managing the desktop so it's safe to add in any case.